# Why does Android stack trace show 'SourceFile' with the option off?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

With a recent upgrade of the project to newest Android API compile/target, and and new build tools version, I am seeing `SourceFile:XYZ` in stack traces, even though `renamesourcefileattribute` is not present in the mapping rules.

Is there a way to turn it off? It seems to be implictly set as `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile`.

EDIT:
It seems like it's getting this from the default proguard rules, but it doesn't look like I can override it in my custom proguard rules?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an issue with Gradle version 2.2.0. They introduced this rule in the default proguard rules. More details [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222775). The temporary solution is to paste contents of default mapping rules into your custom rules (excluding this rename rule), or to wait for next release.